Wear OS app freezes when re-opened from recent apps after device sleeps
I’m experiencing an issue with my Wear OS app where it freezes when I try to re-open it from the recent apps list after the device has been idle and the screen has turned off. Here’s the sequence of events that leads to the freeze:

My Wear OS device goes to sleep after about 15 seconds of inactivity.
If I wait around 2 minutes and 30 seconds, then attempt to re-open the app from the recent apps menu, the app appears frozen.
No interactions are possible within the app during this freeze.

When I look at my logs, I notice that no new logs are generated when the app is frozen, which indicates that none of the Activity lifecycle methods like onResume() or onStart() are being called during this time. This seems to suggest the app isn’t fully re-entering the foreground state. However, if I open the app from scratch (not from recent apps), it opens without any issues (because it completely restarts the app).
Oddly enough, if I leave the app in this frozen state and the device goes to sleep again after the usual 15-second timeout, all the previously queued actions (like lifecycle logs I would expect on onResume() where it freezes) suddenly appear in the log.
Here’s what I’ve tried so far:

Added log statements to every lifecycle method of all activities, but none are triggered when re-opening the app from recent apps (only when the app is relaunched from scratch).
Removed logic in onPause and onStop which had no effect

Has anyone experienced similar behavior on Wear OS, or have any ideas on what might cause the app to freeze in this way?
Thank you for any insights or suggestions you might have!

This is not an answer to your question, but additional insight.
First of all, great job on your analysis. It's spot on to what I've found out myself.
I've noticed that even a blank Flutter app (created with default settings) has the same freezing behavior on Wear OS devices under the conditions you described. This suggests that the problem stems from how Flutter interacts with Wear OS specifically, rather than an issue within your app's code.
From a technical standpoint, this issue seems to be unique to Wear OS due to differences in how the operating system manages app lifecycles and background processes compared to standard Android devices. Wear OS imposes stricter limitations on background activities to conserve battery life and optimize performance for wearable devices with limited resources (Link).
I'm currently looking this as well and will provide an update on any discoveries.

Solution - Updated 11/18/2024
I have pushed the files to a fresh GitHub repo with the required changes. Please refer to the README in https://github.com/CorbinIvon/flutter_ambient_mode_files
The solution / Workaround: Setting up AmbientModeSupport.
After setting this up, your app will no longer freeze. My app has not experienced any freezing after making these changes, and a fresh project seems to also show this fix working.
Something to do with how Wear OS attempts to optimize battery power.
Hope this helps!

Thank you for your comment. Glad to see that I'm not the only one experiencing issues here. Since I created this issue here I also made some more analysis and also had this behavior in the wear os sample apps from google, which lead to my conclusion it's definitely a wear os bug. I've created a google issue for this and they told me they shared it with their engineering team. I will also update if I get any updates from them.

Rick, I have updated my response. I hope you find this useful and can at least use it as guidance for your own solution.
